# How to apply Spotify API authentication on my current code which uses Spotify Search API?

Tags: python, json, api, python-requests, spotify

Earlier I was using Spotify's Search API
 without any kind of authentication. But just last week or so, they made their API usage with Authentication only.
So since the past 2-3 days I've not been able to figure how this authorization works for Search API where I as a developer can let users access responses from Search API without having them to login with their Spotify accounts.

Can someone help me with this authorization stuff(The docs from Spotify don't solve my problem :< )

So here's the python code that I was earlier using -

```
import requests
import json

def Spotify(keyword):

    url = "https://api.spotify.com/v1/search?q="+keyword+"&type=track&limit=1"
    headers = {
    'accept': "application/json",
    'access_token':''
    }


    r = requests.get(url=url,headers=headers).text
    jsonwa = json.loads(r)
    name = jsonwa["tracks"]["items"][0]["name"]
    artists = jsonwa["tracks"]["items"][0]["artists"][0]["name"]
    song_preview_url = jsonwa["tracks"]["items"][0]["preview_url"]
    image = jsonwa["tracks"]["items"][0]["album"]["images"][1]["url"]
    return_this = []
    return_this.append(name)
    return_this.append(artists)
    return_this.append(song_preview_url)
    return_this.append(image)
    print return_this
    return return_this

song = "hello"

Spotify(song)
```

Answer (score 0):

Per the [web authorization docs](https://developer.spotify.com/web-api/authorization-guide/):

> All requests to the Spotify Web API require authorization

You'll need your users to grant permission for your app in order to get an access token. The user must be logged in to gran permission.

Once your app is granted permission by the user, you can use the `refresh_token` from that point on, and the user shouldn't need to grant permission again unless they revoke permission for example. You'll need to manage the `access_token` expiration.